# Confusion about second argument to remap_page_range

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

While going through the remap_page_range(), confused about the usage of second argument to it, as pointed out in the following thread, it expect this argument to be a physical address.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch13s02.html

But in the implementation :

```
 int simple_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
 {
     unsigned long offset = vma->vm_pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT;
    
     if (offset >= _&thinsp;_pa(high_memory) || (filp->f_flags & O_SYNC))
         vma->vm_flags |= VM_IO;
     vma->vm_flags |= VM_RESERVED;

     if (remap_page_range(vma->vm_start, offset, 
            vma->vm_end-vma->vm_start, vma->vm_page_prot))
         return -EAGAIN;
     return 0;
 }
```

It is derived from vma->vm_pgoff that seems to the virtual address (related to current user space VMA), then how the offset value is related to physical address ?

***EDIT:***
I see that remap_page_range() is no more part of latest Kernel source and is converted to remap_pfn_range where 3rd argument seems to be page frame number (that is derived from physical address) but I still see vm_pgoff is used for it.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/infiniband/hw/bnxt_re/ib_verbs.c#L3936

So, how vm_pgoff is related to Physical address ?

Comment: @stackinside, Thanks for the reply. Actually, I made mess of it. to be honest I am confused about the "vma->vm_pgoff" , how it is related to physical address, I have now updated the question.

Comment: Also, remember that Linux Device Drivers 2nd edition was written for Linux 2.6. You are comparing the functions described there with the ones in Linux 5.14 (latest). Linux kernel code changes quite fast and quite a lot, so don't expect to see the exact same functions unless you look at the right version of the code.

Comment: `vm_pgoff` is to be interpreted as the offset (in pages) within the file (or other object) being mapped. It is up to the driver to interpret it. The example in LDD3 interprets `vm_pgoff` as an offset in physical address space, but that is not typical for a device driver. Usually, the offset is interpreted as relative to the start of some buffer, or the start of some device memory, or sometimes used as some sort of index.

Comment: However, regarding my previous comment, the third argument passed to `remap_pfn_range` (or `io_remap_pfn_range`) must be a physical page frame number.

Comment: @IanAbbott, one follow up query, how vm_pgoff value is populated, is it come from user space mmap() call ?

Comment: Exactly, it comes from the last parameter of `mmap()` shifted right by `PAGE_SHIFT`.

Comment: Ok, and zero means(as last argument) its the first page address that is then shifted by PAGE_SHIFT ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't need to be interpreted as an absolute physical memory page address. For example, for a regular file, `vm_pgoff` is the offset (in pages) from the beginning of the file. For a character device driver, it might be the offset (in pages) from the beginning of a buffer, for example (but not necessarily).

Comment: Sorry to really bother you for this small stuff, when you say offset (in pages), does it mean page number 5 (for instance) as file is consist of many-2 pages , and for device mapping, it may point to its MMIO register offset ?